# React Open file dialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openfiledialog

I am trying to open a File Dialog Box with React, so that the user can select a folder and save the file in that particular folder, however I cannot manage to do that.  My code looks like this at the moment:-

```
const exportToCSV = (csvData, fileName) => {
    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(csvData);
    const wb = { Sheets: { 'data': ws }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], {type: fileType});
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + fileExtension);
}

const openDialogWindow = () => {
     // Open dialog here and get the folder name
     exportToCSV(csvData, (folderName + fileName))     
};



return (
    <button
    id="btnExportToCSV"
    onClick={(e) => openDialogWindow()}
    >
        Export Tasks To Excel
    </button>
)
```

so in my openDialogWindow, I would like to have the option to open the dialog box, and let the user select a folder that I can then attach to the pre-defined fileName.  This will give the user the option to save the file in his chosen directory.

Is this possible?

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: which package are you using ? can you share a codesandbox link

Comment: I am using these 2 libraries :- import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

Comment: can you update this one with working one, so i can check whats missing on this https://codesandbox.io/s/59579386-so-saving-file-in-a-folder-5nfm0, how are you passing the params csvData, folder and file name

Comment: ok updated your codesandbox.  csvData and Filename are being passed from another compponent, and I want to override the filename with the folderName (which I get from the dialog Box + the exisitng filename

Comment: It's impossible to open browser native Save As... dialog, this is browser settings and feature.Your users may configure it as they like. your users can click right on your link and save as if they want, or you start download automatically